# NSCollectionView deselect multiple selection

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

So I've been investigating on this topic now for quite a bit, but haven't found anything useful related to it. My problem is that I created an NSCollectionView that serves like an image handler, so where you can drop images, select one or even multiple images at a time and delete them if wanted. Selecting the pictures was rather easy and I achieved it with this bit of code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        selectedCells = indexPaths
    }
```

If the selectedCells is changed it will update the collectionView with the respective highlight.

My problem is now deselecting them. If I click on another image or multiple images the previously selected image gets deselected, but if I click on an empty space or on another view nothing happens, here is the problem. How can I deselect the previously selected Image(s) if the view is being unfocused. I already tried the didDeselectItemsAt function but it never gets called since i'm using multiple selection.
I Hope it didn't get too confusing :]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Add a line in your viewdidload self.yourCollectionView.allowMultipleSelection = true....

Comment: Or else there is even another way to do it through storyboard... Select the collectionView in storyboard and find the selection property in attributes inspector... Change it to multiple selection

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry if i brought up a confusion, my problem is not selecting the images, I already checked the multiple selection and i can select multiple images. My problem is that i cannot deselect these images as with multipleselection enabled the didDeselectItemsAt function does not get called. What I'm trying to do is to make all images deselect if the user clicks on another <- This works, but what doesn't is when the users clicks on another view, or on empty space in the same view.

Comment: Related: [collectionView(_:didDeselectItemsAt:) is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570577/collectionview-diddeselectitemsat-is-never-called)