# collectionView(_:didDeselectItemsAt:) is never called

Tags: cocoa, delegates, mouseevent, appkit, nscollectionview

For some reason, my `NSCollectionView` (which uses a custom layout that I wrote) calls its delegate's `collectionView(_:didSelectItemsAt:)` function when I click an item, but not that same delegate's `collectionView(_:didDeselectItemsAt:)` when I click off it.

Here's my basic setup:

```
class MyCollectionViewContainer: NSViewController {
    fileprivate lazy var collectionView: NSCollectionView = {
        let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.customLayout
        collectionView.isSelectable = true
        collectionView.allowsEmptySelection = true
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    }()
}

extension MyCollectionViewContainer: NSCollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {

        print("Selected", indexPaths)

        // Mutate data to reflect that selection
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didDeselectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        print("Deselected", indexPaths)
    }
}
```

"Deselected" is never printed... :/

Comment: Related: [NSCollectionView deselect multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472377/nscollectionview-deselect-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my layout wasn't adding any supplementary views of type [`NSCollectionElementKindInterItemGapIndicator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionelementkindinteritemgapindicator); apparently this is the view that the collection view uses to detect when you click off an item. My quick solution was to add one huge one to my layout that spans the entire collection view, and make its Z index below that of all other items and supplementary views.

Answer (score -1):

We need to set NSCollectionView item selected:

```
 collectionview.isSelectable = true
```

Comment: That seems to just be a line of code from my question

Comment: i had the same issue with my code so with the help of above code of line my issue has solved

Comment: Then you should ask a new question, post your bad code, and answer it with this fix you found. Your answer does not help my question.

Comment: It is wrong _for this question_. If you posted correct HTML code here, it would still be wrong _for this question_.

Comment: It's the same symptoms for a different problem.